# Variable Year Might Not Have Been Initialized

Tags: java

I am trying to compile and run this program for my Java class. Every time I try to compile it says that the variable year might not have been initialized. Well I can't initialize it because it's determined based on what the user enters as their birthyear. Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Thanks. (Also: I changed all of the datatypes to string because when I had them as integers, it said "incompatible types: string cannot be converted to int").

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hundred
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String month;
    String day;
    String year;
    String HundredthBirthday = ((year) + 100);


    System.out.print("Enter the month in which you were born ");
    month = stdIn.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the day of the month on which you were born: ");
    day = stdIn.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the year that you were born ");
    year = stdIn.nextLine();


    System.out.println("Your Hundredth birtday will be on" + month + day + HundredthBirthday + "!");
  } // end main
} // end class Hundred
```

Thank you everyone for the feedback! I don't know why I didn't realize this before. Trying to calculate the "HundredthBirthday" before the user input the year was obviously foolish on my part. And also, I realized that I was using "stdIn.nextLine" where I should have been using "stdIn.nextInt" for certain variables. That's where my "cannot convert string to int" error was coming from.

Here is how I ended up doing it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hundred
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String month;
    int day;
    int Year;

    System.out.print("Enter the month in which you were born: ");
    month = stdIn.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the day of the month on which you were born: ");
    day = stdIn.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the year that you were born: ");
    Year = stdIn.nextInt();

int HundredthBirthday = (Year + 100);

    System.out.println("Your Hundredth birtday will be on " + month +" " + day + " " + HundredthBirthday + "!");
  } // end main
} // end class Hundred
```

Comment: At `((year) + 100)`, how are you supposed to add `100` to something that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Some lambda expression may help - something like `()-> ((Integer.parseInt(year)) + 100)` would let you evaluate it later... Note that you need to convert your string representation of `year` to numeric value.... `"2015" + "100"` is "2015100" which is unlikely value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Define your variables when you initialize them. Also, you can't assign `hundredthBirthday` until after year you get the `year`!

```
// String month;
// String day;
// String year;
System.out.print("Enter the month in which you were born ");
String month = stdIn.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter the day of the month on which you were born: ");
String day = stdIn.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter the year that you were born ");
String year = stdIn.nextLine();
// Presumably, you want a number!
int hundredthBirthday = (Integer.parseInt(year) + 100);
```

**Or**, get your `year`, `month` and `day` as an `int` in the first place (like)

```
System.out.print("Enter the month in which you were born ");
int month = stdIn.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter the day of the month on which you were born: ");
int day = stdIn.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter the year that you were born ");
int year = stdIn.nextInt();
int hundredthBirthday = year + 100;
```

Comment: While this is clearly example code, @Fryguy would be well advised to check the value of `year` to ensure it represents a valid integer before passing it to `parseInt` - otherwise a `NumberFormatException` may be raised.

Comment: @BobJarvis Good point; added alternative using `nextInt()`.

Comment: To be fair, `nextInt` is equally problematic. It still throws exceptions on malformed input.

Answer (score -1):

Local variables (variables inside the method) cannot be used without it being initialized. The default should be null.

You can also do this by setting the variable as instance variable.